# Global PHP Database File

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently making a PHP script and I need some help. Firstly it allows the user to enter database information on a file called install.html which presents a form to the user. The form uses GET to then send that information to a second install file which creates the relevant tables, enters the information into the tables and then allows the user to carry on with the script.

However I was wondering. In the second install file I used:

```
$databaseServer = $_GET["databaseServer"];
```

in order to get the information that was entered into the form. Is there anyway I can then send these variables ($databaseServer, $databaseName, $databaseUser, $databasePassword) to another file called db.php that I will include on top of every file I write that requires an SQL connection. I have looked at GLOBAL variables but they didn't work properly. I could have been doing something wrong however.

Comment: Why not store them in a session? You can't access GET/POST parameters from a page that did not receive them.

Comment: Ah yes! I will give it a try and let you know!

Comment: Also if I can start a session, and access the session variables, there probably wouldn't be any need for a db.php page? Just start the session and use $_SESSION["databaseName"]; or whatever wherever it is needed.

Comment: If the values should not be deleted when the session ends you need to store the settings somehow so you can later re-use them. btw: By storing to SESSION while in the install script you can also change your forms to POST the data, so you don't clutter the browsers address field.

Comment: That works perfectly guys!

Answer (score 1):

You could save a configuration array to a file:

```
<?php

class Config
{
    public $path;

    public function __construct($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    public function store($config)
    {
        $dump = var_export($config, true);
        $dump = '<?php return ' . $dump . ';';
        file_put_contents($this->path, $dump);
    }

    public function retrieve()
    {
        return include $this->path;
    }
}

// Build your config array
$config['database'] = $_GET['database'];
$config['username'] = $_GET['username'];

// Make sure your server can write to this path
$configurator = new Config(__DIR__ . '/config/config.php');

// Save your config
$configurator->store($config);

// Get your config later
$read_config = $configurator->retrieve();

// Check our config against the saved version 
assert($config == $read_config);

var_dump($read_config);
```